# .htaccess for index.php?page=$1 and other pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just inherited a site, where the current redirection rules are as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

This works great.

Now, I have added a videos section where I want to be able to have a URL as follows: `www.site.com/videos/1`, `www.site.com/videos/2`, etc...

To make this work, I changed the rewrite rules to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?test/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?page=test&vid=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This made it all work wonderfully, with the exception of not everything is in the form of `/index.php?page=$1`. For instance there are a few standalone scripts, such as `/print.php?page=receipt&order_id=2014032513533714`, which my new rewrite rules clobber.

What is an appropriate rewrite rule to catch `/` and `/index.php?page=$1` and redirect those to `/` and `/calendar`, `/videos`, `/videos/1` etc but also be able to accept standalone scripts such as `/print.php?etc`, `/sync.php?etc`, etc?

Comment: Unclear on what you want. With 2 rules in place, which URL is causing problem for you?

Comment: Navigating to `http://www.site.com/print.php?page=receipt&order_id=2014032513533714` redirects to `/`. I want to be able to hit `/anyscript.php` as well as rewriting `/index.php?page=calendar' to `http://www.site.com/calendar/`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip existing files/directories:

```
RewriteRule ^/?test/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?page=test&vid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Another quick note, how could I make it so the file `/adm_888.php` rewrites to `/admin` on top of all that?

Comment: That will be: `RewriteRule ^admin/?$ adm_888.php [L]` and it should be before last rule since that is catch all rule.

Comment: I search it for my issue and it was very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
     Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|static|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This kills all the /index.php?page=$1 stuff